# SilverStripe not saving page content

Tags: php, mamp, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

First time dealing with Silverstripe.

I'm on MacOS and installed MAMP, and installed `composer` and ran the command `composer create-project silverstripe/installer example`

Originally navigated to `htttp://localhost:8888/example` and was given an error message that it was missing a `.env`
So I added this:

```
## Environment {#environment}
SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"

## Database {#database}
SS_DATABASE_CHOOSE_NAME="true"
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLDatabase"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD="root"
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="localhost"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="admin"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password"
```

And it redirected me to `{app_url}/example/dev/build` and it seems to have created a lot of files.
However, navigating to the homepage doesn't show the default page content that seems to appear in the tutorial videos.

The pages `home, about, contact` where autogenerated when I the site was build, and I can edit the home the titles, and even create pages, but it doesn't save the content of a page - It says "successfully saved" in the toast message, but then the content disappears.

My `_config.php` looks like this:

```php
<?php

use SilverStripe\Security\PasswordValidator;
use SilverStripe\Security\Member;

// remove PasswordValidator for SilverStripe 5.0
$validator = PasswordValidator::create();
// Settings are registered via Injector configuration - see passwords.yml in framework
Member::set_password_validator($validator);
```

But this differs from the content that appears in the apps repo https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/_config.php
(Not sure if this is expected or something is going wrong with my install)

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

UPDATE:
In Chrome's console, when I try save I see the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/example/admin/pages/edit/EditForm/2/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this who is facing the same issue, I have opened an issue in the SilverStripeInstaller repo https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/issues/273 (It is still being looked into)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the php files in your "app" folder and make sure that there are no preceding whitespace between the opening `<?php` tag in any of the php files you find nested in that folder. Having some whitespace before you php opening tag can cause this kind of issue in Silverstripe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was really hoping this would be the issue, but I checked all the files and unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case :(